# Mean Curvature Flow of graphs

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and let $f:\Omega\times [0,T)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Consider the graph function $\phi:\Omega\times [0,T)\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ given by $\phi(p,t)=(p,f(p,t))$. In general $\phi$ is said to flow in mean curvature if
$$ 
\partial_t \phi=H\nu
$$
Where $H$ is the mean curvature function for the pullback metric $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+f_if_j$ at each time, and 
$$\nu=\frac{(-\nabla f,1)}{1+|\nabla f|^2}$$
is the unit vector perpendicular to the immersed manifold $\phi|_t$.

This is a very common example and yet I get confused. In fact, 
$$\partial_t\phi=(0,...,0,\partial_t f)=\partial_t f\textbf{e}_{n+1}$$
and therefore $\nu||\textbf{e}_{n+1}$ i.e. $\nu=\textbf{e}_{n+1}$, and $\nabla f=0$.

This is clearly ridiculous and yet I cannot find my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is a tangential diffeomorphism that is involved.

In general for any immersion $\phi : M\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$, the MCF equation is $\partial_t \phi=H\nu$. But one can also consider the equation

$$\tag{1} (\partial_t \tilde \phi )^\perp = H\nu, \text{ or } \langle \partial_t \tilde \phi, \nu \rangle = H. $$

The difference is that $\partial _ t\tilde \phi$ might contain non-zero tangential part $X = (\partial_t \tilde \phi)^\top$. However, one can consider a tangential one-parameter groups of diffeomorphisms generated by $X$:

$$\tag{2} y: M \times [0,T) \to M, \ \ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} (y(x, t), t) = X(y(x, t)).$$

Then the composition

$$ \phi (x, t) = \tilde \phi((y(x, t), t)$$

satisfies the usual MCF.

Going back to the graphical cases. We are really solving (1), which becomes

$$ \frac{\partial _t f }{ \sqrt{1+ |\nabla f|^2}} = H\Rightarrow \partial _t f = \sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2} \operatorname{div} \left(\frac{\nabla f}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}\right)
$$

**Remark** The trick to use (1) instead of the usual MCF is called the DeTurck trick and is orginated from Ricci flow. You can see that explained in [here](https://bookstore.ams.org/amsip-32) or p.548 [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01232278.pdf). (a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909169/proposition-2-1-lectures-on-mean-curvature-flow-by-xi-ping-zhu?rq=1))

**Remark** It seeems that whether or not (1) is really equivalent to the MCF depends on whether (2) as a ODE is solvable. When $M$ is compact this can always be done. In the non-compact cases, there might be some reason why (2) can always be solving, but I cannot find it in literature (As you can see in Ecker-Huisken's paper, they did not even bother to explain). In fact a doubt is raised in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589508/different-equations-for-mean-curvature-flow) MSE post